# Android SDK Examples

Tags: android

My Android emulator contains A list of 'API Demos', including a nice looking password PIN form (with validation) within the App->Device Admin section.

Any idea where the source can be found? Or does anyone know of a good example off a user PIN input sample?

Answer (score 1):

All the examples are included with the Eclipse ADT plugin, I think. Start a new "Android Example" project and you can choose any of the samples.

Answer (score 1):

The samples source and project can be found in your sdk directory. Specifically under `ANDROID_SDK/samples/android-XX/ApiDemos` *(where `XX` is a certain API level)*

If the samples folder is not present, you have to install the samples via the SDK manager first.